# Como recibir desde la firebase Storage un archivo .txt y leerlo en android studio

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas tardes,
Tenia la duda de como es posible conseguir jalar de la firebase storage un documento de texto y leerlo en mi aplicacion de android studio. Lo que pasa que llevo buscandolo ya todo el dia y no encuentro ningun lugar donde explique como obtener un archivo de texto desde la storage de firebase y leerlo, si alguien me puede aclarar la duda seria de gran ayuda. 
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Diego, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Comment: La cuestion seria como leer el archivo desde Firebase storage sin descargar. Yo me he leido montones de veces esa pagina y no he sacado nada en claro, llevo dos meses intentando buscando por internet y no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar. Todos idem de lo mismo, descargar imagenes... A ver si alguien tiene la bondad de solucionarnoslo.

Answer (score 1):

No es muy complicado, primero creas un path donde esta guardado el archivo en firebase

```
StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg");
```

Luego creas un FilePath dentro del dispositivo donde se va a guardar el archivo

```
File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
```

Por ultimo obtienes el archivo con `getFile()`

```
pathReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created

           //Aqui ya obtuviste el archivo, asi que puedes chequear su tamaño con
     un log   

    Log.e("Tamaño del archivo",""+datasnapshot.getByteCount(); //creo que era byte count pero con un get byte obtenias el tamaño del archivo
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Luego si quieres puedes poner `localFile.getAbsolutePath()` y obtener donde tienes guardado el archivo txt

Espero te sirva, todo lo que te escribi lo obtuve de la documentacion oficial de firebase, donde puedes encontrar como guardar en memoria, y otras opciones de guardado, te recomiendo que leas la documentacion [Aquí](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419)